# WPML Get url without outputting

Tags: urls, multi-language, plugin-wpml

I am in the process of migrating from qTranslate to WPML to handle my languages.

With qTranslate, I had a very simple way to get an url to a page or post knowing it's slug: `$url = get_language_url(home_url($slug));`

Now with WPML I can't find a way to do that...

There's the `icl_link_to_element` function but it directly outputs the link in a a tag.. Besides, you need to know the post ID.

Any way I can get a link to a post in the correct language, knowing it's slug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually Wordpress lacks a real function to get posts by slug/post-name. But you can use [get_page_by_path()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) for it so you don't have to use a custom query:

```
if(function_exists('icl_object_id')) {
   $post = get_page_by_path('your-slug');
   $id = icl_object_id($post->ID,'post',true);
   $link = get_permalink($id);
}
```

The only difference here is that you must use the full path i.e. (`'parent-page/sub-page'`) if you have a hierarchical structure. For posts and non-hierarchical pages you can just use the slug as param.

Answer (score 0):

You can get link to a post by it's slug using following code.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = 'name-of-slug'");
    if(function_exists('icl_object_id')){
        get_permalink(icl_object_id($id,'post',true)); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: How would you do this for the "current page", without needing to know the slug etc?